# Is this lizard protected or endangered?

Tags: conservation-biology, herpetology

We think that it's a type of alligator lizard. It was found in the open space area near my home in Moss Beach California (about 10 miles south of San Francisco). Thank you!  [image]

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be a California Alligator Lizard - Elgaria multicarinata (subspecies multicarinata), although another photo from the side would be helpful for a positive ID. This species seems to fit the range for the observation as well.

According to CaliforniaHerps.com, there are no associated conservation concerns for this particular species.

[Elgaria multicarinata multicarinata conservation status](http://www.californiaherps.com/lizards/pages/e.m.multicarinata.html#status)